# Constructing an isomorphism between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I am trying to come up with an isomorphism of $X$ and ker$(f \oplus g)$, where   $f \oplus g: X \oplus Y \to Z$, and $f: X \to Z$ is a homomorphism and $g:Y \to Z$ is an isomorphism of commutative groups.

Somehow I am totally out of ideas. Would be grateful for any kind help.

Comment: Given $x\in X$, there is one and only one $y\in Y$ such that $f(x) = g(y)$ (prove this). In particular, how many elements of the form $(x,a)$ can lie in $\mathrm{ker}(f\oplus g)$?

Comment: Should be at most the cardinality of $X$?

Comment: For *each* fixed $x$, how many $a\in Y$ can you put in the second coordinate to get an element of $\mathrm{ker}(f\oplus g)$?

Comment: Sorry, should be |ker($g$)| then

Comment: And given that $g$ is an *iso*morphism, what is the cardinality of its kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\pi : \ker(f\oplus g)\to X$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x.$

We have $\ker\pi = \{(x,y)\in X\oplus Y\mid x = 0\textrm{ and }f(x) + g(y) = 0\}$ But, if $x = 0,$ then we must have $g(y) = -f(0) = 0,$ and as $g : Y\to Z$ is an isomorphism, there is a unique such $y\in Y;$ namely, $y = 0.$ This shows that $\pi$ is injective.

On the other hand, let $x_0\in X.$ Then as $g : Y\to Z$ is an isomorphism, there exists a unique $y_0\in Y$ such that $g(y_0) = -f(x_0).$ This means that $f\oplus g(x_0,y_0) = f(x_0) + (-f(x_0)) = 0,$ so $(x_0,y_0)\in\ker(f\oplus g).$ As $\pi(x_0,y_0) = x_0,$ $\pi$ is also surjective.